# Relative Pronoun

Tags: grammaticality, relative-pronouns

Is the following sentence grammatically correct?

> This is the man, who I told you about, raised 6 million dollar to our company.

If it's ungrammatical, what makes it so?

Comment: Sorry, correction on "English native speaker".

Comment: [This](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) is a more suitable place to ask this question.

Answer (score 1):

> This is the man, who I told you about, raised 6 million dollar to our company.

Yes, a non-native English speaker might in fact word your sentence that way. Only after becoming more fluent in English might he or she then word the sentence as follows:

> This is the man whom I told you about, who raised six million dollars for our company.

*Whom* is used in the sentence's first part because the objective case is needed, as in "I told you about ***him.***" (*Him* and *whom* are objective case pronouns).

*Who* is used in the second part of the sentence because the nominative case is needed, as in "He/she raised six million dollars." (*He* and *she* are nominative case pronouns.)

With less-formal wording, an English speaker could also say,

> This is the man I told you about who raised six million dollars for our company.

Or,

> This is the man I told you about. He raised six million dollars for our company.

Comment: The use of 'who' (or even 'that') rather than 'whom' here is largely accepted.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Looks as though (or is "looks like" accepted today?) I need to get a bit more up to date in my pronouncements. A thousand pardons, Sahib. Don

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: 'that' I would agree with, but 'whom'  is still used by those to whom clarity is important, partly to avoid repeating 'who' in constructions like OPs.

Comment: @TimLymington Are you saying that clarity isn't important to John Lawler?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I'm confused. How does John Lawler fit into this discussion? I'm just curious. Don

Comment: To quote him on this perennial: "The best advice about the use of _whom_ is

Don't bother to use whom. Ever, at all.
Whom is dead. It's an ex-pronoun. It's joined the bleedin' choir invisible."